# How to display the information from the input box

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to learn how to work with angular and javascript more.  Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

When I input something into the text box, it should display

> "hello {name} , would you like to play a game?

It displays the string without the input.

Also, when I run it, it says

> object Object

.

```
(function (app) {
var JakesController = function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.JakesSampleModel = {name: ' '};
$scope.theSampleReturn = null;

var sendResponseData = function (response) {
        if (response.data.error) {
           console.log(data);
        }
        else {
            $scope.theSampleReturn = response.data;
        }
    };

    var sendResponseError = function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }

    $scope.senddata = function (params) {
        return $http({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/home/servercall',
            data: params
        })
            .then(sendResponseData)
            .catch(sendResponseError);
    };
};

app.controller("JakesController",['$scope', '$http', JakesController]);

}(angular.module("JakesFirstApp")));
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="OutterDiv" ng-controller="JakesController" ng-app="JakesFirstApp">
<div id="JakesButton" class="button" ng-click="senddata()">Submit</div>
<input type="text" id="JakesTextBox" ng-model="theSampleReturn" />
{{theSampleReturn.result}}
```

Json result:

```
public JsonResult servercall(string name)
    {
        return Json(new { result = $"Hello {name}, Would you like to play a game?" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, then it looks like the solution is to update your template like so:

```
<input type="text" id="JakesTextBox" ng-model="JakesSampleModel.name" />
```

And then update your controller to correctly send the name to the server when `senddata()` is called:

```
$scope.senddata = function () {

    // Construct params for post by getting data from your scope/model that's
    // wired up to your input field
    var params = { name : $scope.JakesSampleModel.name };

    return $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/home/servercall',
        data: params
    })
    .then(sendResponseData)
    .catch(sendResponseError);
};
```

Comment: @Jake you're welcome - all the best with your project :-)

Answer (score 1):

In your html try to use {{theSampleReturn}} instead of {{theSampleReturn.result}} because you don't seem to have theSampleReturn.result set anywhere